# How can I change Imagebutton location?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want to change the `ImageButton` location when click the `ImageButton`. I use that code but it doesn't work. Code :

```
imb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            LayoutParams ibPar = (LayoutParams) imb.getLayoutParams();


            Random randomIntGenerator = new Random();
            int randomLocationX = randomIntGenerator.nextInt(100);
            int randomLocationY = randomIntGenerator.nextInt(400);

            ibPar.x = randomLocationX;
            ibPar.y = randomLocationY;
            imb.setLayoutParams(ibPar);             }
    });
```

There is an error at `LayoutParams ibPar = (LayoutParams) imb.getLayoutParams()`. Why?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: What type of view is your parent?  It may not respect those parameters.  And at any rate, you'll need to call requestLayout on your parent to tell it that you updated your parameters and need to relayout.

Comment: what is the type of LayoutParams i.e it should be of view or ImageView.Check your imports . and as it already returnign layout params no need to cast

Comment: Add here your logcat, please.

Comment: Is it a compilation error or runtime problem?